# What is the limit for $x$ approaching zero of the dirac delta distribution $\delta(x)$?

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta

I am trying to prove that
$$
\lim_{y\rightarrow 0} \delta(y-x) = \delta(x)
.$$

To justify this problem, this comes from the orthogonality of the position eigenstates in quantum mechanics. Indeed, we have that $\langle x|y \rangle = \delta(x-y)$, but what happens if $y$ approaches $x$?

This looks trivial, but what if $x=0$?
If we think of the delta as something which is equal to zero everywhere but in zero, then we should have $\lim_{y\rightarrow 0} \delta(y) = 0$, while from the identity above we would have $\lim_{y\rightarrow 0} \delta(y) = \delta(0)$. I think that, in this case, the problem is in the definition of the delta.

So I tried the following:

consider a continuous function $f$:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x)\delta(x)dx = f(0) = \lim_{y\rightarrow 0} f(y) = \lim_{y \rightarrow 0} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x)\delta(x-y)dx = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x) \left(\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\delta(x-y) \right) dx
$$
and since it has to hold for every continuous $f$, we have $$\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\delta(x-y) = \delta(x) .$$ However, I'm not really sure that everything works since I'm swapping the limit and the integral, and this could require more assumptions.

I tried to use also other definitions of $\delta$ as distribution but I always have to swap limits and I'm not sure I can have enough assumptions to do it.

To conclude, I would like to have an answer to $\lim_{y \rightarrow 0} \delta(y) = ?$, but since it could be not well defined, feel free to use related topics like the orthonormality of states or other definitions of delta.

Comment: When you say you're trying to *prove* this, what is the rigorous definition of the $\delta$ adn the limit that you're using? it's not a function, after all.

Comment: "Indeed, we have that $<x|y> = \delta(x-y)$ and $<x|x>=1$." Um, indeed not... $<x|x>$ is not equal to 1, if $<x|y>=\delta(x-y)$.

Comment: These continuous $|x>$ kets are not physical states and they are not normalized to 1.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was wrong about the normalized definition I gave of the position eigenstates. I corrected the question, I hope now is right. As for the definition of delta, I tried to use both the definition as a distribution and the definition as the object such that, when integrated with a function, gives the function evaluated in zero, but both approaches require the swap of limits I'm not sure about.

Comment: A "delta function" is not actually a *function* despite its name. This is why all the definitions of a delta "function" are so weird. For some supposed "definitions" of a delta "function" the limit as the function argument approaches zero is indeed zero. But since the value of the function for non-zero argument is also zero, this means this "function" should also integrate to zero. So, you see the kind of paradoxical problems that can arise by treating the delta function as a *function* from real numbers to real numbers. It is better described as a "functional."

Comment: The term "functional" is used by physicists to refer to a function that takes *functions* as input and outputs numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Dirac delta at a point $y\in\Bbb R^d$, $\delta_y(x) := \delta(x-y)$ is defined as a distribution by its action on test functions $\varphi\in C^\infty_c$ through the formula
$$
\langle \delta_y,\varphi\rangle = \int_{\Bbb R^d} \varphi(x)\,\delta_y(\mathrm d x) = \varphi(y).
$$
In particular, since $\varphi$ is continuous, $\varphi(y)\to\varphi(0)$ when $y\to 0$, which implies that
$$
\langle \delta_y,\varphi\rangle \underset{y\to 0}{\to} \langle \delta_0,\varphi\rangle
$$
that is
$$
\delta_y \underset{y\to 0}{\to} \delta_0 \text{ in the sense of distributions,}
$$
which you can write symbolically, $\delta(x-y) \underset{y\to 0}{\to} \delta(x)$.